# how to make text clickable in tkinter python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, vlc, clickable

I am writing a program in python on Ubuntu, to import and print the names of video files from a folder but It is printing as  a simple text, not in a click-able form.

I want to make them clickable & open on video player 'vlc' on one click.

Can you plz guide me to do that?

```
import io,sys,os,subprocess 
from Tkinter import *

def viewFile():
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if f.endswith(".h264"):
            tex.insert(END,f + "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    mainframe= root.title("FILE MANAGER APPLICATION")                         # Program Objective
    mainframe= root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

    step = LabelFrame(root,text="FILE MANAGER", font = "Arial 20 bold   italic")
    step.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=100, pady=5, ipadx=130, ipady=25)

    Button(step,    text="File View",   font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=30, height=5, command=viewFile).grid      (row= 1, column =2)
    Button(step,    text="Exit",        font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=20, height=5, command=root.quit).grid     (row= 1, column =5)

    tex = Text(master=root)
    scr=Scrollbar(root,orient =VERTICAL,command=tex.yview)
    scr.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=15, columnspan=1, sticky=NS)
    tex.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
    tex.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set,font=('Arial', 8, 'bold', 'italic'))

    global process
    path = os.path.expanduser("~/python")                   # Define path To play, delete, or rename video
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add tags to spans of characters in the text widget, and you can set bindings on tags. So, a simple solution is to create a unique tag for each filename, and a unique binding for that tag.

For example:

```
def viewFile():
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if f.endswith(".h264"):
            linkname="link-" + f
            tex.insert(END,f + "\n", linkname)
            tex.tag_configure(linkname, foreground="blue", underline=True)
            tex.tag_bind(linkname, "<1>", lambda event, filename=f: openFile(filename))
```

This will cause a function named `openFile` to be called with one argument, which is the filename. You can then do whatever you want in that function.

Comment: How do I open this on vlc player by one-click

Comment: I get error
**tex.tag_bind(linkname, "<1>", lambda event, filename=f: open(filename))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'video.h264'**

Comment: @FahadUddin: probably because it's just passing the name of the file, not the whole path. You'll likely want to pass the whole path. This was just an illustration of how to make clickable text, not a complete solution to your problem.

Comment: how do i tell Openfile to open this file on VLC because after mentioning the correct path .... on command line cursor is just blinking

Comment: @FahadUddin: that's a different question. The comment section isn't intended to be for extended discussions.

Answer (score 2):

try this line in the last to open video on VLC

```
tex.tag_bind(linkname, "<1>", lambda event, filename =path+'/'+f: subprocess.call(['vlc',filename]))
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do this is loop over all the files and create a button for each with the file name like so

```
 fram = Frame(root)
 files = os.listdir(path):
 for f in range(0, len(files), 1):
    if files[f].endswith(".h264"):
        name = files[f].split(".")
        b = Button(fram, text=name[0])
        b.bind('<Button>', openV)
        b.grid(row=f, column=1)
```

now your `openV` fuction should look like this to actually open the file

```
def openV(event):
     b = event.widget()
     properties = b.config() #get all config for this widget, conveniently the only value right now is text
     n = properties[0]
     bashCommand = "vlc " + n + ".h264" # this is the command to actually be exectuted
     os.system(bashCommand)
```

make sure you have python-swap installed on your system or you will get an error with `os.system()`
you do not need to have unique ids since 2 files with the same name and extension in the same folder cannot exist!

Comment: First how do I install python-swap and It is given an syntax error on line 2